# Execute code after reloading page on Navigation.GoBack()

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `Window` that only has one frame to show the different pages that my application has.

When a `Page loads`, it initializes several threads that deal with different elements of the UI. When I change the page with `frame.Navigate(new NextPage())` I abort those threads, as it doesn't make sense to keep them running when the page is not in the foreground.

The problem comes when I make `frame.GoBack()`, since I have no way to relaunch those treads on the page because no code is executed when I return to the page.

There is something similar to the OnPause, OnStart, OnStop method of Android but for WPF and pages?

Something like the following:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var thread = new Thread(() => Code());
    thread.Start();
}

public Code()
{
    // Do Stuff
}

public Continue()
{
    thread.abort()
    frame.Navigate(new NextPage()) 
}

public OnPageReloaded()
{
    thread.start()
}
```

Comment: don't abort the threads and don't dispose the page

Comment: Some of these threads are for going back after a timeout. If I don't abort these threads, it will call frame.GoBack() when I'm on another page.

Comment: so implement a logic to prevent them from calling GoBack. or abort some of them and pause the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) and create tasks instead of threads. Calling `Abort()` on a thread is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort).

As to your actual question, you could initialize your work in the `Loaded` event handler of the `Page` instead of doing it in the constructor:

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += Page1_Loaded;
    }

    private void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //start your tasks here...
    }
}
```

The `Loaded` event will be invoked each time your `Page` instance is being navigated to. There is also an `Unloaded` event that you can use to do cleanup.